# Adding data to Google Sheets without authentication (R + googlesheets)

Tags: r, shiny, r-googlesheets

Is it possible to add rows to an existing public Google Sheet without prompting for user authentication? I have the following function in a shiny app:

```
update <- function(URL, date, value){
    URL %>%
        gs_url() %>%
        gs_add_row(ws = 3, input = c(date, value))
}
```

but when `gs_add_row` is called locally, it opens a browser asking to sign into a Google account. On shinyapps.io it crashes (causes the session to disconnect from the server).

I have made sure the Google Sheet is "published to the web."

Comment: https://rawgit.com/jennybc/googlesheets/master/vignettes/managing-auth-tokens.html#how-to-completely-avoid-reading-this-document

Comment: I think you can read from the table without authentication, but I don't think you can write to it without authentication.

Comment: Yes, reading works without authentication. Ok, after authenticating, when run locally, it can write to the Google Sheet. But on shinyapps.io it doesn't redirect to a browser and just crashes. Any workaround?